# BizTalk XSLT + If not equal is not working

Tags: xslt, biztalk

I have two source schema and one destination. I would like to compare Source 1 against Source 2 and map non matching data from Source 2 to destination.

Below is my inline XSLT but I am not getting the expected output. Looks like it is mapping all the data from Source 2

Is this the proper way doing "not equal" in XSLT?

The first snippet is the schema; the second snippet is the XSLT.

```html
<!- Source Schema 2-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:INT_XROOT xmlns:ns0="http://Append_WAW_Files.Schema_INT_XML">
  <INT_XDATA>
    <BranchIdentifier>EMPLOYEE PLAN</BranchIdentifier>
    <Insured>Kyle Foster</Insured>
    <PolicyNumber>7V5230758</PolicyNumber>
    <EffectiveDate>03/01/2013</EffectiveDate>
    <TransType>BTC</TransType>
    <CommPercent>12.5</CommPercent>
    <CommAmount>-124.50</CommAmount>
    <PremiumAmount>-996.00</PremiumAmount>
  </INT_XDATA>
  <INT_XDATA>
    <BranchIdentifier>EMPLOYEE PLAN</BranchIdentifier>
    <Insured>MILLER, VICKI &amp; RICHAR</Insured>
    <PolicyNumber>702572173</PolicyNumber>
    <EffectiveDate>02/06/2014</EffectiveDate>
    <TransType>RNR</TransType>
    <CommPercent>5.0</CommPercent>
    <CommAmount>8.65</CommAmount>
    <PremiumAmount>-173.00</PremiumAmount>
  </INT_XDATA>
  <TxnID>1</TxnID>
</ns0:INT_XROOT>
```

```html
<!- Source Schema 1-->

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:TAM_XROOT xmlns:ns0="http://Append_WAW_Files.Schema.TAM_Output_XML">
  <TAM_XDATA>
    <Source>TAM</Source>
    <MonthStatement>201402</MonthStatement>
    <BranchIdentifier/>
    <Region>NAB</Region>
    <BillType/>
    <Insured>Kyle Foster</Insured>
    <PolicyNumber>7V5230758</PolicyNumber>
    <EffectiveDate>03/01/2013</EffectiveDate>
    <TransType>-EN</TransType>
    <CommPercent>12.5</CommPercent>
    <CommAmount>-124.50</CommAmount>
    <PremiumAmount>-996.00</PremiumAmount>
    <CompanyCode>WAW</CompanyCode>
    <Status/>
    <Notes/>
    <MonthProduction/>
    <CustomerRec>FOSTKY1</CustomerRec>
    <Item>9G6B54</Item>
    <Desc/>
    <LongPolicyNumber/>
  </TAM_XDATA>
  <TAM_XDATA>
    <Source>TAM</Source>
    <MonthStatement>201402</MonthStatement>
    <BranchIdentifier/>
    <Region>NAB</Region>
    <BillType/>
    <Insured>Bengu Karahasan</Insured>
    <PolicyNumber>RMZBNG8581</PolicyNumber>
    <EffectiveDate>03/02/2015</EffectiveDate>
    <TransType>+EN</TransType>
    <CommPercent>12.0</CommPercent>
    <CommAmount>200.20</CommAmount>
    <PremiumAmount>350.00</PremiumAmount>
    <CompanyCode>WAW</CompanyCode>
    <Status/>
    <Notes/>
    <MonthProduction/>
    <CustomerRec>FOSTKY1</CustomerRec>
    <Item>9G6B5B</Item>
    <Desc/>
    <LongPolicyNumber/>
  </TAM_XDATA>
  <TxnID>1</TxnID>
</ns0:TAM_XROOT>
```

```html
<Schema>
  Root
    INT_DATA
       Source 
       MonthStatement
       BranchIdentifier
       Region
       BillType 
       Insured
       PolicyNumber
       EffectiveDate 
       TransType 
       CommPercent 
       CommAmount
       PremiumAmount 
       CompanyCode 
       Status 
       Notes 
       MonthProduction
       CustomerRec 
       Item
       Desc 
       LongPolicyNumber



<xsl:template name="ValidateTransactionData">

<!-- Loop MessagePart_0 -->
<xsl:for-each select="InputMessagePart_0/s1:INT_XROOT/INT_XDATA">

<!-- Create "Matching_DATA" record in the output message for each matching transaction-->   

<xsl:variable name="s1_PolicyNumber" select="PolicyNumber"/>
<xsl:variable name="s1_EffectiveDate" select="EffectiveDate"/>
<xsl:variable name="s1_CommPercent" select="CommPercent"/>
<xsl:variable name="s1_CommAmount" select="CommAmount"/>
<xsl:variable name="s1_PremiumAmount" select="PremiumAmount"/>


<!-- Loop InputMessagePart_1 and validate matching long policy number --> 
<xsl:for-each select="../../../InputMessagePart_1/s0:TAM_XROOT/TAM_XDATA">
<xsl:variable name="s0_PolicyNumber" select="PolicyNumber"/>
<xsl:variable name="s0_EffectiveDate" select="EffectiveDate"/>
<xsl:variable name="s0_CommPercent" select="CommPercent"/>
<xsl:variable name="s0_CommAmount" select="CommAmount"/>
<xsl:variable name="s0_PremiumAmount" select="PremiumAmount"/>


<xsl:if test="($s0_PolicyNumber != $s1_PolicyNumber) or (s0_EffectiveDate != $s1_EffectiveDate) or (s0_CommPercent != $s1_CommPercent) or (s0_CommAmount != $s1_CommAmount) or (s0_PremiumAmount != $s1_PremiumAmount)">

<INT_UDATA>
<Source>
<xsl:value-of select="Source" />
</Source>

<MonthStatement>
<xsl:value-of select="MonthStatement" />
</MonthStatement>

<BranchIdentifier>
<xsl:value-of select="BranchIdentifier" />
</BranchIdentifier>

<Region>
<xsl:value-of select="Region" />
</Region>

<BillType>
<xsl:value-of select="BillType" />
</BillType>

<Insured>
<xsl:value-of select="Insured" />
</Insured>

<PolicyNumber>
<xsl:value-of select="PolicyNumber" />
</PolicyNumber >

<EffectiveDate>
<xsl:value-of select="EffectiveDate" />
</EffectiveDate >

<CommPercent>
<xsl:value-of select="CommPercent" />
</CommPercent>

<CommAmount>
<xsl:value-of select="CommAmount" />
</CommAmount>

<PremiumAmount>
<xsl:value-of select="PremiumAmount" />
</PremiumAmount>

<CompanyCode>
<xsl:value-of select="CompanyCode" />
</CompanyCode>

<Status>
<xsl:value-of select="Status" />
</Status>

<Notes>
<xsl:value-of select="Notes" />
</Notes>

<MonthProduction>
<xsl:value-of select="MonthProduction" />
</MonthProduction>

<CustomerRec>
<xsl:value-of select="CustomerRec" />
</CustomerRec>

<Item>
<xsl:value-of select="Item" />
</Item>

<Desc>
<xsl:value-of select="Desc" />
</Desc>

</INT_UDATA >
<xsl:value-of select="./text()" />

</xsl:if>               
</xsl:for-each >    
<xsl:value-of select="./text()" />              

</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="./text()" />

</xsl:template >
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition

```
<xsl:if test="($s0_PolicyNumber != $s1_PolicyNumber) or (s0_EffectiveDate != $s1_EffectiveDate) or (s0_CommPercent != $s1_CommPercent) or (s0_CommAmount != $s1_CommAmount) or (s0_PremiumAmount != $s1_PremiumAmount)">
```

"$" is missing in some places.

Comment: yes I have noticed that but that is not the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating the strings all together and compare those.

For example:

```
<xsl:variable name="s0" select="concat(s0_PolicyNumber, s0_EffectiveDate, s0_CommPercent, s0_CommAmount, s0_PremiumAmount)"/>
<xsl:variable name="s1" select="concat(s1_PolicyNumber, s1_EffectiveDate, s1_CommPercent, s1_CommAmount, s1_PremiumAmount)"/>

<xsl:if test="$s0 != $s1">
...
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: That looks like might work I will try. However moving forward there is going to be +/- 5cent for the Premium amount. If Premium amount is less or above 5 cent of the original amount (source 2) wont get into condition and will be accepted as valid. Any idea on that manner?

Comment: concat the fixed values and then have an additional xsl:if for that new requirement.
Seeing your question: you're sure this additional requirement was not the source of your problem?

Comment: unfortunately concat did not help. Drives me crazy!!! 
Condition looks like duplicating data. First block of data looks good but then script copies everything from Source and creates 10 block of same data.

Comment: Please provide your input xml as well, so we can take a look at that.

Comment: please look at the original post i added the schema. Map is the orchestration and has two input all the schemas are identically the same. You can also find the screenshot from the link I shared  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_eNSohB12jKUEZRY01OQWNSUms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, Please provide a sample xml which you are using as a basis for testing your map. I can't do a thing with what you provided now I'm afraid.

Comment: okay could you please provide me your email or my email is remzi.krh@gmail.com Thanks

Comment: This site is about helping people out and also allowing people to be able to help you by providing enough information. Please edit your question with your input XML (or a dumbed down version) as this might - one day - help someone else out in time.

Comment: I added sample input schemas I am trying to validate Source 2 schema against Source 1 and if any of the elements I use in the xslt script aren't matching I would like to map that record from Source 2 to destination.